# Python Tutorial Question: Ends With Function

Tags: python

I have a python tutorial question which i couldn't get past. The question as follow:

**Ends With**
Given two strings, return True if either of the strings appears at the very end of the other string, ignoring upper/lower case differences (in other words, the computation should not be "case sensitive").

My solution:

```
def end_other(a,b):     
    s1=a.lower()    
    s2=b.lower()   
    if len(s1)>len(s2):  
        if s1[-len(s2)]==s2[-len(s2)]:  
            return True  
    if len(s1)<len(s2):  
        if s1[-len(s1)]==s2[-len(s1)]:  
            return True  
    if len(s1)==len(s2):  
        if s1[-len(s1)]==s2[-len(s2)]:  
            return True  
    else:  
         return False
```

But the Error Message window shows: All the public tests passed but some private tests failed. You need to generalize your solution.

What is the problem lies in my solution? Or is there somethings i missed?

Comment: What would happen with `end_other("", "")`? :)

Comment: you should at least be comparing slices instead of just one character

Answer (score 17):

What about using python's builtin [`str.endswith()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) method?

```
def end_other(a, b):
    a_lower = a.lower()
    b_lower = b.lower()
    return a_lower.endswith(b_lower) or b_lower.endswith(a_lower)
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this is what you were actually trying to do:

```
def end_other ( a, b ):
    a = a.lower()
    b = b.lower()
    if a == b:
        return True
    elif len( a ) > len( b ):
        return b == a[-len( b ):]
    else:
        return a == b[-len( a ):]
```

You had a couple of mistakes in your solution:

- `s1[-len(s2)]` or generally `s1[x]` just gets a single character. So if anything, you are just comparing a single character, but not an actual sequence of characters. You splice a sequence out of a string by `s[x:y]` (see the manual).
- `s2[-len(s2)]`, even with the colon as explained above, doesn't make much sense. You are accessing `s2` using its own length. But as `s2` is already the smaller string, you can compare it as a whole.
- When one of your outer ifs matches a situation, there is no way any other of the outer situations can follow. For example if `a` is *longer* than `b`, there is no way that `a` will be shorter or of the same length as `b` later on. As such you should make your if structure support that. Instead of `if ... if ... if ... else` make a chain: `if ... elif ... elif ... else`. Then one automatically knows that only one of those cases can apply.
- When you do that, you can also leave off the last `if` expression. Because when neither `x < y` nor `y < x` equals to true, then `x` is equal to `y`.
- You also need to change the way you return from within the function. As of now you have a conditional exit within each of your outer if cases. Now if the first if case applies (i.e. `s1` is longer than `s2`) and the inner if does not apply (`s1` does not end with `s2`), then you already know that the function should return False. Because there is no way that any other condition later in the code says otherwise, so you should return False immediately there (especially when there is other code that might execute later). And when you have `if x: return True else: return False` then you can just `return x`.
- `s1[-len(s1)]==s2[-len(s2)]`: As other as already said you will have a problem when `s1` and `s2` are empty strings. `len( "" ) = 0` and if both strings are empty, then both lengths are identical. And then your code tries to use an index range on an empty string, which will always fail (as there is not a single character). Instead, when you already know that two strings are of the same size, just compare both as a whole. This also helps against empty strings.

Anyway, if you didn't need to implement it on your own, you should really use `str.endswith` instead.

Comment: Good answer. Though I might add a minor efficieny point to your solution. When `len(a) == len(b)` but not `a == b` your code with make two checks to see if the strings are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Comparison using an empty string will implode. And use `.endswith()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
def ends_with(str1, str2):
    str1 = str1.lower()
    str2 = str2.lower()
    return str1.endswith(str2) or str2.endswith(str1)
```

Comment: Doesn't compare lowercased versions. And the entire `if` construct should be dropped. `return` the result of the comparison directly - that's already `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is comparing just one character from each string.  You might have wanted to use slicing notation, but you left the colon out of the brackets.  Your code will give true for "---ba" and "bc", for example.  Then, you don't return False when len(s1) != len(s2); however, Python functions always return something, and this defaults to None, so that error might go undetected (as None evaluates as falsy) for some time.

```
def either_endswith_lower(a, b):
  n = min(len(a), len(b))
  return a[-n:].lower() == b[-n:].lower()
```

This is a tutorial you're following, but I'd prefer to drop the lowercasing in the function and have users call func(a.lower(), b.lower()) if that's what they desire.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, [ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster)'s answer is the most elegant one.

Now just to fix your code, taking into account [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke)'s remarks:

```
def end_other(a,b):
    s1=a.lower()    
    s2=b.lower()   
    if len(s1)>len(s2):  
        if s1[-len(s2):]==s2:  
            return True  
    elif len(s1)<len(s2):  
        if s1==s2[-len(s1):]:  
            return True  
    else:  
        return s1 == s2;
    return False
```

I just used simple rules to simplify it:

- use `if`/`elif`/`else` block instead of 3 `if`s since the 3 cases are mutually exclusive
- `s[-len(s):]` is equivalent to `s`